# How to access viewModel in Knockout component?

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to preopulate a knockout component on document ready.

I've written the following code:

```
function Finding(id, trigger) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.trigger = ko.observable(trigger);
}

function FindingViewModel() {
    let self = this;

    self.findings = ko.observableArray();

    self.addFinding = function () {
        self.findings.push(new Finding(self.findings().length + 1, ""));
    };
    self.removeFinding = function (finding) {
        self.findings.remove(finding);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.findings(), function (value, i) {
            self.findings.replace(value, new Finding(i + 1, value.trigger()));
        });
    };
    self.update = function (data) {
        var findings = data.findings;
        for (var index = 0; index < findings.length; ++index) {
            var finding = findings[index];
            self.findings.push(new Finding(self.findings().length + 1, finding.trigger));
        }

    };
}

ko.components.register('finding', {
    template: `<table>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: findings">
            <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: id"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: trigger"/></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFinding">Remove</a></td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
            <button data-bind="click: addFinding">Add a Finding</button>`,

    viewModel: FindingViewModel

});

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings();
    $.getJSON("/_get_findings", function (data) {
        //findingModel.update(data);
    })
});
```

How can I access the underlying Viewmodel from the finding component to set data from inside the getJSON function?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the component was used multiple times on the page? At first sight, it seems to make more sense to have the `$.getJSON` call inside the view model constructor function and have it execute once per component instance.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will try that! Thx

Comment: Awesome! It worked. thank You very much! BR Jörn

Answer (score 1):

thx to Jeroen the solution looks like this:

```
function FindingViewModel() {
    let self = this;

    self.findings = ko.observableArray();


    self.addFinding = function () {
        self.findings.push(new Finding(self.findings().length + 1, ""));
    };

    self.removeFinding = function (finding) {
        self.findings.remove(finding);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.findings(), function (value, i) {
            self.findings.replace(value, new Finding(i + 1, value.trigger()));
        });
    };

    self.update = function (data) {
        let findings = data.findings;
        for (let index = 0; index < findings.length; ++index) {
            let finding = findings[index];
            self.findings.push(new Finding(self.findings().length + 1, finding.trigger));
        }

    };

    $.getJSON("/_get_findings", function (data) {
        self.update(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Good to see it worked. Careful though, you seem to have a few syntax errors in the exact answer you've posted.